# Simple Pantheon panel applet on eOS?

Tags: python, linux, api, pantheon

I would like to make a simple applet for the Pantheon Panel on eOS Luna with Python. I can't find any documentation on any API. It's been suggested on some forum I should use the same procedure as Gnome or Unity. The applets I have tried, however (like the one on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094506/simple-gnome-panel-applet-in-python)), simply didn't work.

Could you guide me a little towards what I should be doing to have a simple applet icon + menu showing on the Pantheon panel?

Answer (score 0):

It seems one has to use the App Indicator module as per Ubuntu documentation. The `appindicator` package of PyGtk didn't work out, but the PyGi `AppIndicator3` does work fine as far as I can tell.

A simple example is:

```
#!/usr/env/bin/ python
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

def menuitem_response(w, buf):
  print buf

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ind = appindicator.Indicator.new (
                        "example-simple-client",
                        "indicator-messages",
                        appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
  ind.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
  ind.set_attention_icon ("indicator-messages-new")

  menu = Gtk.Menu()

  for i in range(3):
    buf = "Test-undermenu - %d" % i

    menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem(buf)

    menu.append(menu_items)

    menu_items.show()

  ind.set_menu(menu)

  Gtk.main()
```

Example drawn from [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/).